# The semaphore timeout period has expired when scanning for broken links

Tags: link-database, broken-links

I looked everywhere but I could not find an answer, so here I am.

I tried to run Sitecore's broken link report (in Control Panel > Reports > Scan the database for broken links) but got the below message. Have any of you encountered this?

---

> An error occured
>
> Job started: ScanBrokenLinks|System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving
> results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The
> semaphore timeout period has expired.) --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The semaphore
> timeout period has expired
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
> at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
> at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, UInt32 error)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[]
> buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadString(Int32
> length, String& value)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer
> value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp,
> TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value,
> SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
> SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String
> columnName)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i,
> Boolean readHeaderOnly)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean
> setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
>
> at Sitecore.Links.SqlLinkDatabase.AddBrokenLinks(IDataReader reader,
> List`1 links, Database database)
>
> at Sitecore.Links.SqlLinkDatabase.GetBrokenLinks(Database database)
>
> at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Tools.BrokenLinks.BrokenLinksForm.Scanner.Scan(Boolean
> excludeSystemItems)
>
> ClientConnectionId:fa92cfc7-d9f6-46ae-9d63-0c564d375123
>
> Error Number:121,State:0,Class:20|Job ended: ScanBrokenLinks (units
> processed: )

Comment: <command name="system:brokenlinks" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.System.BrokenLinks,Sitecore.Kernel"/> this command is responible to create report, If you didn't find a solution then you can debug this.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that I cannot reproduce this locally. It happens only on prod. It works on UAT as well as it works on my dev machine.

Comment: Can you try to restore Prod database in dev and then reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a field name called "Link". I changed the field name to anything else than "Link" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue while removing Roles from RoleManger, after that unicorn sync stopped working.
I found the proper explanation in the below link.
Not sure if it will resolve your problem but it fixed the issue for me.

[Follow the below link and other resolutions as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13285480/9869635)